# Deploy Nginx, Socket IO, Linode 404 error

Tags: node.js, sockets, nginx, deployment, socket.io

I have been struggling trying to deploy a NodeJS server as SocketIO server on Linode. I have deployed my Django projects that works fine and I have redirected a subdomain to talk to the node server listening on port 8002 of local host.
I get a 404 error in my nginx log.

```
"GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling HTTP/1.1" 404 72 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.0.1; LG-D850 Build/LRX21Y)"
```

**Here is my nginx config**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.domain.com;
        location / {
                 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        }
        location /static {
                alias /home/exampledir/staticfiles;
        }
        access_log  /home/exampledir/nginx-access.log;
        error_log  /home/exampledir/nginx-error.log info;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server subdomain.domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }
}
```

**Here is my nodejs server file**

```
var socket = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(8002, '127.0.0.1');
var io = socket.listen(server);
var redis = require('redis');
var sub = redis.createClient();
sub.subscribe('notify');
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('join', function (data) {
        ...
    });
});
//Grab message from Redis and send to client
sub.on('message', function(channel, message){
...
});
```

I have tried using CORS and stuff but it does not work just keeps giving me a 404. I have verified the node server is running at 127.0.0.1:8002
My android socket is connecting to

```
mSocket = IO.socket("http://subdomain.domain.com/);
```

Please help.

Comment: Have you confirmed that http://127.0.0.1:8002/socket.io on the app server comes back as expected? Do you have a means of testing a complete WebSocket negotiation directly to the NodeJS port? If you're following the example from https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/, have you set up the variable map for $connection_upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this config

```
server {

    listen 80;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/

    server_name domain.com;

    location / {

             proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;

    }


    location / {

             proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;

    }

    location /static {

            alias /home/example-dir/staticfiles;

    }

    access_log  /home/example-dir/nginx-access.log;

    error_log  /home/example-dir/nginx-error.log info;

  }



 server {

    listen 80;

    server_name subdomain.domain.com;

    location / {

            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8002;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;

            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;

            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

            proxy_set_header Host $host;

    }

    access_log  /home/example-dir/socketnginx-access.log;

    error_log  /home/example-dir/socketnginx-error.log info;

   }
```